# linux mint 20.1 is always using my CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, linux-mint, gpu

well guys I am a Win user and I want to turn to linux mint

so first I try this OS on a bootable flash and everything was fine

but when I want to do a screen record or some staff on the net it seems that this OS always use my CPU to process the tasks and it is not going to use my GPU and Understood this when I look at my cpu and gpu temperatures:

cpu : 40 Celsius and it turns to 60 while I am screen recording

gpu : 46 Celsius and it turns to 47 while I am screen recording

but in Win it isn't like that .

Well I have a weak CPU processors and I don't want to use them like this . If my GPU come to the ring too the CPU processors can get some rest .

Why this is happening ? should I install linux mint on my hard disk to solve the problem ?
should I install my gpu driver on this os to solve the problem? ....

simple explanation would be better.thanks

Comment: What GPU do you have? If it is Nvidia, you have to load the proprietary drivers, and launch your application using it, or set it as default for the entire Xsession with the Nvidia settings applet.

Comment: @acejavelin Its Nvidia :)

Comment: @acejavelin well as a Win user I didn't understand what do U mean . I just know how to install drivers. would you explain it as simple as possible

Comment: @acejavelin Is linux mint OS compatible with Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Well, Mint is essentially Ubuntu with a different DE and some tools added, so yeah... Just open Driver Manager (it's an app in the menus) and install the recommended drivers and reboot. Driver Manager is one of the first things you should be doing if you went through the Welcome Screen options. :)

Comment: Once the drivers are installed, it is similar to how it works in Windows... For most applications to use the dedicated GPU, you have to right click and select "Run with dedicated graphics" or launch with a special parameter (usually adding DRI_PRIME=1 to the beginning of the command), or add it as an application profile in the Nvidia control panel applet.

Comment: I have a feeling this is going to turn into a discussion and be much more than a Q&A thing... I love using Superuser, but this discussion might be better suited to r/linuxmint sub-Reddit, the Linux Mint Help for Beginners FB group, or the Linux Mint group on MeWe. Superuser isn't really intended for a drawn out discussion.